# MySQL - best data type for simple time with hours and minutes

Tags: mysql, performance

I need to represent the due time for tasks in my MySQL 5 database.
Then, I need to store times like these:
_ 18
_ 9:15
_ 12:00

Now I am in dilemma whether to use the time datatype or just a 4-digit integer as I just need to store hours and minutes.
In the second case, I would store:
_ 1800
_ 0915
_ 1200

What are the implication of both the approaches?
Which solution would you implement given that the most important requirement is high performance in a huge dataset (millions of rows)?

The application code is written in PHP.

**EDIT:** I was thinking of an important point. If I use integers, I need to do some string manipulation with PHP when I display the time (to insert the semicolon) that probably nullify the gain with using integers

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: You need high performance in what case? Querying millions of rows? Inserting? Ordering?

Answer (score 12):

Use `time` datatype. Main benefit will be reusing existing time function embedded in MySQL.

It will probably be more efficient in terms of space using a `smallint` (only 2 bytes) but you will loose the ability to use existing functions to operate on fields whose semantic is a `time` value. I can think of formatting functions, time difference, time zones as examples of scenarios where you could take immediate advantage of the `time` datatype.

Answer (score 6):

MySQL's `TIME` data type only takes 3 bytes. Use it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html